# No display in getorgchart print preview

Tags: php, getorgchart

I'm working on a symfony project and I am using the GetOrgChart to create organizational chart. All is working except for printing, I have set the enablePrint to true and I have also inserted my target document element(people) inside a div but still no display in print preview. Can anyone help me? thanks

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="people"></div
</div>

var orgchart = new getOrgChart(document.getElementById("people"),{
enablePrint: true,
dataSource: [
    {id: 1, parentId: null, Name: "Amber McKenzie"},
    { id: 2, parentId: 1, Name: "Ava Field"},
    { id: 3, parentId: 1, Name: "Evie Johnson"}
]
});
```

Comment: Please give some code, we couldnt figure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: edit your question and add the syntax, not in the comment section